# python - function prints whole file, but only prints one line outside function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to search a file for the chromosomes I want, such as `chr1`.

I parsed the file to get only the columns I want in the function `get_columns()`.  When I print the parsed filed in the function it works fine.  However, when I try to search for a word using the returned file, it seems as though it is only giving me the first line. I assigned the variable `search_file` to the function and when I print this out I get only the first line of my parsed file. How can I search for my chromosome throughout the whole file I parsed in the first function?

```
#! /usr/bin/python    

input_file = open( "Code_Work/GenFile.txt", "rU" )

def get_columns (myFile):    
    for aRow in myFile:
        no_new = aRow.lstrip("\n")
        split = no_new.split('\t')
        sec_split = split[8].split(';')

        new_file =  split[0] + "\t" + split[3] + "\t" + split[4] + "\t" + split[6]  + "\t"  + sec_split[0]  + "\t" + sec_split[1]  + "\t" + sec_split[2]

        return new_file            

search_file = get_columns(input_file)


import re
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
print re.findall(r"\b" +  re.escape(original) + "[\w]*", search_file)

input_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return` statement inside your `for` loop. That means your function always returns after the first line.